# How I can free an assembly after loading it using reflection?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I noticed in testing, that multiple calls to the following code creates a memory leak :

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(arg2.DeclaringType.FullName));
arg2.Invoke(obj, new object[] { arg3 });
```

*For the above code, `arg2` is `MethodInfo` type ;  `arg3` is `string[]`*

Even if I add `obj = null;` after the Invoke, it seems that GAC doesn't collect this object for cleanup. (yes, I know setting an object to null is a poor excuse for dispose(), however as this is a generic method, there may or may not be a dispose() available in the class, and tested with assemblies that do have dispose, they are not unloaded after use)

I have consider using a cache mechanism where the loaded assembly is stored in a dictionary for subsequent lookups, however there is no guarantee that GAC won't come and clean it up later making that object in dictionary unusable (among other disasters).

How can I force an unload of the class (similar to the way I can force it to load by calling `Activate`) once I am finished with it ?

Comment: Do you want to free now an assembly in the AppDomain or dispose an instance of an object? You're title and text are misleading

Comment: `obj = null` is pointless, in general, for a local variable. The JIT and GC collaborate to "understand" the lifetime of the reference, and as soon as no other piece of code is going to *read* from `obj`, it will no longer keep the object it references alive. No help from you is required.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I should probably clarify a bit on my testing.  I opened the UI, and did the action which called the above code (click event) numerous times.  Each click, memory usage increased.  I was able to have it go (slowly) from 36MB used to 100MB used after several clicks. The only action the click does is load this assembly, reflect the method, and exit.

Comment: `GAC won't come and clean it up later making that object in dictionary unusable` <= I really hope not otherwise all .net developers would be in serious trouble. As long as there exists an active reference it will not get collected by GC. Also you do not have to worry about loading an assembly reference in a dictionary unless you have a very specific technical requirement to do so.

Comment: @Igor - was considering more for caching purposes as it appears to create a new instance of the assembly on each click. (due to the steady memory usage increase of the assembly loaded on each click event) (possibly i am not naming it correctly.  I wish to unload that particular instantiation of that class or whatever is loaded when I call `Activator` )

Comment: `The only action the click does is load this assembly` <= how are you loading the assembly (also why?)? There are many ways to do this and it is possible to load the same assembly multiple times in the same app domain (if you are doing it incorrectly). This would be a problem but one easily fixed by using the correct method to load it in.

Comment: @Igor - In summary, this is part of a callback which hooks the link click inside a webbrowser control so I have the full power of html5/etc, and can harness c# from the browser control to application level. (not keen on xaml for ui design) - have pseudo-uri's like `method://mymethod/param1/param2/param3` so unless there is a non-reflection method to call a method/function by the name as a string this is what I am stuck with

Comment: Ok, but just to be clear there is no other code you are calling to load the assembly into memory other than what you posted in your question?

Comment: @Igor, that is correct.

Comment: Then you are doing it correctly and I would not worry about the memory. `GC` runs every so often (its non deterministic as far as when it runs, it has to do with many factors including memory pressure) and it will free up memory used by the instances you create in the above manner assuming they are no longer referenced anywhere. This  assumes that the instances you are creating are not of types that implement `IDisposable` or are using non-managed code, which could have a problem.

Comment: If you still think the behavior is not normal I would start by looking into the type that is being instantiated and see what it does but the code above in itself is ok.

Comment: Ok.  I will keep an eye on it.  If it is behaving as intended, then the matter is closed. If I notice that GC isn't releasing at runtime/production, the will revisit my code to ensure nothing else is using at that time, and if not, I may need to revisit this issue even though there may not really be anything that can be done, it is worth a shot.  Aside from GC.Collect() there doesn't appear to be any other real control over this which is kind of a bummer. Trading control for convenience :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get this straight, [you can not unload an assembly when it has been loaded unless you unload the entire Application Domain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632258.aspx).

(and if you want to know why : [check this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasonz/2004/05/31/why-isnt-there-an-assembly-unload-method/))

However, with a class it is different, you are talking about releasing it from memory. First of all, are you sure that no other object have an access to it ?

When you are sure of that, know that the Garbage Collector will release the memory of the unreferenced objects whenever it wants to, so talking about memory leak might be a bit prematured...

You can however [force the Garbage Collector to clean up the memory by calling GC.Collect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I will try to force GC, but as you said, I may have to wait until the application decides it is no longer in use for it to cleanup anyway - or just cache the class since it seems to be kind of stuck for an indefinite period anyway to prevent it from being loaded more than once.